# Java IO - Folder Creation Error

Tags: java

I am not able to create a folder using following code.

```
import java.io.File;

public class Fileupload
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        File f = new File("C:\\BOS\\BOS-5.8-Tomcat-6.0.35\\webapps\\bonita\\ECR-DZ-00013\\Ranjeet\\");
        if (f.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("Already Present");
        }
        else
        {
            f.mkdir();
            System.out.println("Created");
        }
    }
 }
```

If I remove my name "Ranjeet" from the path then it gets created, otherwise folder is not created by the same code.

Comment: Can you provide the program output when it doesn't work (i.e. stacktrace)

Comment: Can you give us the result of calling f.canWrite() and f.canRead() on the file object?  If either of those are false it explains your problem.

Comment: If you're using Java SE 7, consider to use the new NIO.2 File API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html

Comment: I have ranjeet still its not working. I am not saying there is any error in your code

Answer (score 9):

We don't know enough to be *sure* that this is the answer, but...

[`mkdir`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29) relies on the parent directory already existing. So it won't be able to create the `Ranjeet` directory unless `ECR-DZ-00013` already exists.

However, you can use [`mkdirs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) instead which creates all the intermediate directories as required:

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the necessary parent directories.